# How to default an IP address to https on Jetty

Tags: jetty

Using Jetty as a application server. If I type the IP address in the browser, how can I make it default to https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to configure a connector for https as described here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html

If you want to only allow https then add a security constraint to your web application as described here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html#bncbm

That will redirect all requests send to the http connector to the https connector.